# What is the most minimal xaml element that can change a DataContext?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm wondering what element can be used, when the only thing you want to change is the DataContext.

I'm aware that I could wrap it in a grid or something, but all of those are rather heavy weight when I just need to change the data context for a single element, so that I can more easily bind to attributes without them getting too long.

Comment: You could just change the DataContext of the element itself no?

Comment: Yes, possibly, in some scenarios. I'm interested in an answer still for the sake of education.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of the WPF class hierarchy is described at [Microsoft: WPF Architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/wpf-architecture?view=netframework-4.7.2). There you can find the [System.Windows.FrameworkElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/wpf-architecture?view=netframework-4.7.2#systemwindowsframeworkelement):

> The two most critical things that FrameworkElement introduces are data binding and styles.

Checking the properties of [FrameworkElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement?view=netframework-4.7.2), there the `DataContext` property is defined. This means the following capability is available:

> Support for data binding and dynamic resource references: The property-level support for data binding and resources is implemented by the DependencyProperty class and embodied in the property system, but the ability to resolve a member value that is stored as an Expression (the programming construct that underlies both data binding and dynamic resources) is implemented by FrameworkElement. For more information, see Data Binding Overview and XAML Resources.

The [Data​Context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext?view=netframework-4.7.2) property is now available and used at all inherited controls, which you can see at the following class hierarchy:
[image: class hierarchy]

Comment: Can FrameWorkElement be used directly in xaml? What is the first descendant that can be?

Comment: Yes, you are able to use `FrameworkElement` in XAML.